# Swift: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Tags: swift

On this line: `let task = self.session.venues.get(self.foursquareId!) {`

```
import UIKit
import QuadratTouch

class VenueDetailsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var venueLabelName: UILabel!

    var foursquareId:String?
    var session: Session!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let task = self.session.venues.get(self.foursquareId!) {
            (result) -> Void in
            if result.response != nil {
                if let venue = result.response!["venue"] as? JSONParameters {
                    if let venueName = venue["name"] as? String {
                        self.venueLabelName.text = venueName
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Show error.
            }
        }
        task.start()

    }
}
```

It throws me a

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

Comment: Put it in an if let command. It should be solved

Comment: Not if foursquareId is nil... Only if if the self.session.venues.get() function accepts optional values and returns an optional, and foursquareId was not force-unwrapped. There should already be an if at the beginning of that line anyways.

Comment: @bryanm foursquareId is getting passed a string and is not nil. If I println it before the `task = ` I can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `session` is nil, or `foursquareId` is nil. Since `session` is implicitly unwrapped, it will throw an error on that line as well as if `foursquaerId` is nil. You'll need to make sure these values are set before you attempt to access them like this.

Comment: foursquareId is not nil because I'm able to see it if I println() it. I think the session is the culprit. Didn't I set the session before already? `var session: Session!` ?

Comment: @Ryan No, you declared it as an implicitly unwrapped optional variable. You are basically saying that you will set it before it's used, but are not actually setting it to any value just by declaring it there.

Comment: Ah I see. So `var session: Session?` and then `task = self.session!.venues.get()` Would that set the value properly?

Comment: @Ryan No, you would end up with the same problem. The value is nil, you need to set it somewhere else in the code. i.e. `self.session = Session()`

Comment: I see, Thanks. So I did, `self.session = Session()` just before `task =` and ow I'm getting "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Session' with no arguments."

Comment: Got it with `self.session = Session.sharedSession()` Thanks for the help!